# Django migrations without db table rewrites

Tags: django, django-models, migration, database-migration

I have a huge table and I don't want to cause a table rewrite or so.

so in my model I first created a field like this:

```
field = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

then executed makemigrations, then changed my field to

```
field = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
```

executed makemigrations again and second migration looks like this:

```
migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='game',
        name='field',
        field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
    ),
```

Would this cause a table rewrite? I know I will still have Null values in the previous rows but I want to make this work for the next rows without causing DB downtime.

My db is PostgreSQL.

and first migration looks like this, if helpful:

```
migrations.AddField(
        model_name='game',
        name='field',
        field=models.IntegerField(null=True),
    ),
```

Comment: I just checked sqlmigrate and this definitely causes table rewrite, so how can I make this without table rewrites?

Comment: If you are worried about DB downtime, why not just export the database to your development or test Django instance, run the migration there, then replace the records on your production DB (after checking if there is a delta and handling appropriately)?